# Disk defragmentor in Windows stops at 0% on Pass 1, and just shows fragmentation %, how do I resolve this?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, defragment

I'd like to defragment a drive that is 81% fragmented. The problem is Windows on  my desktop at school and my laptop wont help it get past 0% before the action seemingly stops completely. 
The Desktop's specs are:

1. Windows 10 Enterprise
2. 16GB DDR3 RAM
3. intel Core i5-2500K 3.30GHz CPU
4. 500GB HDD

My laptop's specs are (the laptop is an ASUS X550LA):

1. Windows 10 Education
2. 8GB DDR3 RAM
3. Intel Core i7-4500U 1.8GHz
4. 1TB HDD

The drive in question is a:

- Western Digital
- Blue
- 500GB
- 2.5"

Comment: Please better define what happens when it "stops completely".  Is it just sitting at 0%, or does it actually stop and/or exit? If it just sits at 0%: Does the Performance Monitor show disk activity?  How long have you left it sitting for before giving up?

Comment: I updated the question, It should help. It just stops at 0% and shows the fragmentation percentage.

Comment: Windows 10 should have a scheduled defragmentation run.  Can you check the Event logs for any error that might be arising.

Comment: I could, but I never got an error message. Eh, it wouldn't hurt to check Event Veiwer

Comment: You should be confident that the filesystem is intact before you perform a defrag.  IOW perform a `chkdisk` first.

Comment: I just ran chkdisk and I'm waiting on pass 1. I'll let you know if there is progress

Comment: 0% but at least it hasn't stopped pass 1 yet